# Google Sheets Query with Date and Time

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I need help with a query.  I need to filter on some Google Form data and only show the results that have been submitted AFTER a specific timestamp.

Timestamp Cell = `J2` - This cell is in the following format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Day Query - This one seems to work ok but its only at the day level.

```
=query(FormResponses!A2:G,"Select * Where A > date '"&text(J2,"YYYY-mm-dd") & "'" )
```

Time of Day Query - This one also seems to work ok but only at the time level.

```
=query(FormResponses!A2:G,"Select * Where A > timeofday'" & text(J2, "HH:mm:ss") & "'" )
```

When I try to combine the two, it returns no results and I can not figure out why.  I do see some wierd issues with the ">" in the queries above so i am second guessing the accuracy of the above queries to begin with.  Does anyone have a sample of checking both date and time in a google sheets query?

Comment: See if this link works.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fbVNGM9qVcVRwEmqgP6Ga3oaPOhM2bzOEjxOWWbWNyY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks that worked with importrange and cell reference too. Demo here: https://i.imgur.com/N82AZG0.gif

Comment: Time Format Note: The time input needs to be formated as time and not text otherwise the  `#N/A :Query completed with an empty output.` error is thrown. So far I could only find that way to format time from text to time format: `=TIME(MID(K14,1,2),MID(K14,4,2),MID(K14,7,2))` with full example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748966/is-there-a-to-date-time-equivalent-function-in-google-sheets-something-like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(TO_DATE(QUERY(VALUE(QUERY(FormResponses!A2:A, 
 "select *", 0)), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 > "&VALUE(J2), 0)), 
 {VALUE(FormResponses!A2:A), FormResponses!B2:G}, 
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works perfectly.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I can see there is already an answer, but is there any reason that you can't just use the `Filter` command?

Something like the below:

```
=FILTER(FormResponses!A1:G,FormResponses!A:A>$J$2)
```

I added it to your shared sheet, please let me know if it was unsuitable.