# Google Sheets average analysis by time value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image]

[Link to test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4QsGh_KLmHCAAy_n7B8dQASyFpEz7xbywXrtQKC2xQ/edit?usp=sharing)

In the above segment of a wider Google sheet I want to analyse the results of test1 test2 and test3 according to the time of the test to the extent that I wish to average all results taken in the dark yellow range (Matin 00:00 - 10:00), the yellow range (Jour 10:00 - 16:00) and the blue range (Soir 16:00 - 23:59).

The timing colour coding comes from underlying conditional formatting and the test results similarly for readability purposes (nothing more).

Problem:

using `=iferror(AVERAGEIF(V5:V35; "<>0");"")` for test1 will generally seems to work but extending that formula to test2 `=AVERAGEIFs(W5:W35;U5:U35; "<=10:00")` and so test3 `=AVERAGEIFs(X5:X35;U5:U35; "<=10:00")` will result in an incorrect results in test2 since times in test1 will be included as will results in tes3 because the results in test1 and test2 will be included as the meet the criterion specified.

In Soir, test1 I have attempted to overcome this by using the following formula `=query(u24:v34, "Select Avg(V) where U '<=09:59'")` but this  causes a formula parse error.

EDIT #1:
The tests are performed daily (where blank no test that day was carried out) and there are 3 measures each test (see the test sheet) Column A represents the day of the month. The intention is summarise in the table at line 37 the 3 tests. Line 37 is the average overall for each test and what is required is to expand that in lines 38, 39, 40 to anaylyse the overall results in line 37 to show how it differs for the different time periods. The 3 tests actually relate to blood pressure -  systolic, diastolic and Pulse rates respectively (abbreviated to test1,2 & 3 for simplicity and clarity).

EDIT #2 29 Jan 21 (15:45)
In test sheet - "test analysis logic" tab (derived from Copie de Test) following intervention by @Oleg_S the conditional ranges have been modified and the number of results reduced to 6 - 2 from each time period of three to provide a more easy to follow test bed which appears to give the expected result. A second opinion on my understanding of that success would be useful.

Am I taking the right approach to solving this conundrum or is there a better way to make sure that the analysis of results in the various time slots are correctly reported?

Comment: Try using =query(u24:v34, "Select Avg(V) where U <= timeofday '09:59:00'")


Link to similar question
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88774/query-or-filter-the-data-where-the-start-time-is-past-300-pm

Comment: @Oleg_S Thanks. I tried your suggestion and it returns a parse error. I changed the comma to a semi-colon (u24:v34;) due to locale and it returns the string avg to cell V40 and the number 8 to cell V41. However, that still won't select only records `between` times, will it?

Comment: @Oleg_S further analysis of the result figure 8 in V41 and what it represents is unclear.I have provided a link in the question to the sheet.

Comment: Still don't fully understand if Time in Column U is only for test1, or for all tests.
Following is for assumption that time is one for all tests, in other case you'd need 2 more time columns. Added Copy of your Sheet.

Comment: @Oleg_S sorry, my bad explanation. The time in column U is for all tests. The 3 tests are part of the same event so at that time, 3 values are recorded. I've added a further clarification in the body of the question.

Comment: @Oleg_S I have added EDIT #2 to the question and created a further test bed in the [linked test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4QsGh_KLmHCAAy_n7B8dQASyFpEz7xbywXrtQKC2xQ/edit#gid=90919166). Could you check it out for me please? If you agree, please put that together as an answer which I can accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Oleg_S now corrected cell colour logic conditional formats and assembly of analysis in the corresponding table. To avoid div0 errors on sheets without data, each is protected by a `iferror()` formula.

Comment: I posted an answer but can't do more because the link is dead.

Comment: "because the link is dead" Unsurprising - When creating a [Google Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) You can use and edit your Blank Sheet for the next 30 days then it will automatically be set to View Only for archive and future educational purposes. The OP was 4 years ago  The matter was resolved in my comment on 30 Jan 2021!

Answer (score 0):

## A.   `Avg.All` Averages All Tests

```
=LET(hr,A1:A25, tests,B1:D25,
   start,{0;0;10;16}, end,{24;10;16;24},
   {{"Avg.All"; "Avg.Matin"; "Avg.Jour"; "Avg.Soir"},
     MAP(start,end, LAMBDA(s,e, BYCOL(tests, LAMBDA(t, 
       ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGEIF(
         t*(hr>=s/24)*(hr<e/24),">0"))))))})
```

- If the time periods don't have an equal number of tests, then it could be the case that `Avg.All <> AVERAGE(Avg.Matin, Avg.Jour, Avg.Soir)`

## B.  `Avg.All` Averages all Averages

```
=LET(hr,U5:U34, tests,V5:X34,
  start,{0;10;16}, end,{10;16;24},
  lbl,{"Avg.All"; "Avg.Matin"; "Avg.Jour"; "Avg.Soir"},
  avg,MAP(start,end, LAMBDA(s,e, BYCOL(tests, LAMBDA(t, 
    ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGEIF(
      t*(hr>=s/24)*(hr<e/24),">0")))))),
  {lbl,{BYCOL(avg, LAMBDA(c, AVERAGE(c))); avg}})
```

- If the time periods don't have an equal number of tests, then `Avg.All` may not be an accurate representation of the average of all tests but it will always be the case that   `Avg.All = AVERAGE(Avg.Matin, Avg.Jour, Avg.Soir)`

---

## Images

**A.   `Avg.All` Averages All Tests**
[image: Averages All Tests]

**B.   `Avg.All` Averages all Averages**
[image: Averages All Tests]